# Google API (youtube search) always sorts results by relevance instead of date

Tags: youtube-api

I use Google API to get a JSON result of my own YouTube channel videos.
The URL has not changed, but suddenly, Google returns the JSON only with order=relevant instead of order by date.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCqEcEGQ0sG89j7ZhOdgFOyg&maxResults=24&order=date&type=video&videoType=any&key=<key>
```

The first result returned will be a 2 year old video instead of yesterday's one.

This call did work 'till last week (week 11 2016)

Comment: after playing with this issue i found if use the "q" parameter the results will be sorted by date accordingly, so "searching" for something common works just fine.. but filters elements that do not match the search ... maybe a good temporary solution

Comment: this turned out to have resolved itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [thread](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/2494861?hl=en), it seems it is a bug and that the YouTube team is aware of it. A Google employee responded 3 days ago with:

> YouTube is aware the search/sorting functions aren't working as
>   expected – this is temporary and part of our efforts to better
>   respond, review and remove graphic, violative content from YouTube.
>   Thanks for your patience while we work through this. Will update this
>   thread when these features are working normally again, feel free to
>   subscribe for updates.

You can subscribe to the thread for faster updates.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, yes that makes perfect sense, since it worked fine for years without any change. it's kind of sad that Google is still unable to tell developers about such changes. a lot of youtubers have serious issues with this as well as this changes can massive impact the revenue stream.